# Spreadsheet navigation template

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

Every once in a while, I think about writing a spreadsheet front end for my database tables.
Before I get started with interpreting whether the left arrow means to move left one digit or whether it means to move one cell to the left...

Is there a JavaScript routine for navigating around a <table> element on the screen and being able to modify <td> text?

I suppose then I'd have to hook an $.ajax call whenever the user changes a cell.

I ♡ jQuery and ColdFusion.

Comment: I guess you could decide that based on the state of the "cell", if active (editable) vs. inactive. That probably can be set by adding/removing classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/editable.html